# CNN can't learn - "oscillating" loss function and classifier that marks every sample with same label

Tags: classification, python, conv-neural-network, loss-functions

I would be really thankful for any hint as I have no idea what to do next.

I am trying to create a working convolutional neural network for an image classification task. There is a 96x96 RGB image as an input and the net is supposed to determine one of three classes. The cross entropy loss and Adam model are used.

The problem is that my classifier labels all the samples with one class. The loss function also doesn't look good and I can't find a way to fix this. On the graph it looks almost like a periodic function. Take a look at the example values during the training:

[image]

This is my PyTorch CNN:

```
class Network(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Network, self).__init__()

    self.conv_seq1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 8, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU()
    )

    self.conv_seq2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(8, 16, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU()
    )

    self.conv_seq3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2)
    )

    n = 32 * 48 * 48

    self.linear_seq = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(n, int(n / 64)),
        nn.Linear(int(n / 64), 3)
    )

def forward(self, data):
    output = self.conv_seq1(data)
    output = self.conv_seq2(output)
    output = self.conv_seq3(output)

    output = output.reshape(output.size(0), -1)
    output = self.linear_seq(output)

    return output
```

What I've tried:

- Increasing and decreasing learning rate value
- Using small and big datasets (from 60 to 7500 samples)
- Adding weights to the classes (but I did it kinda blindly just to check)
- Using minibatches of different sizes

And yet nothing helped. Is there anything more I could do?

Comment: Can't tell you what's wrong, but I can tell immediately that *something* is off based on the fact that your binary CE loss is greater than $\log 2$, which should never happen. In fact the loss should start off at something very close to $\log 2$.

Comment: @shimao based on the output size of the final layer I think there are 3 classes. Do you mean that the loss should start near log(3)?

Comment: @Sycorax oh I did misread -- seems that the weights / loss starts off in the right place, in that case

Comment: You’re using crossentropy loss but the output of your final layer isn’t scaled to be a probability; If I were a gambler, I’d bet that’s your problem. This is one of the bugs explicitly listed in my answer to “What should I do when my neural network doesn’t learn?”

Comment: Thank you, guys. @Sycorax correct me if I'm wrong but I use [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) which uses [Softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#softmax) that should take care about scaling the output to the probability format. Isn't that enough?

Comment: I guess you're right. I didn't realize that in pytorch, CrossEntropyLoss combined softmax and xe loss into a single function. In other libraries, it's different.

Comment: So no other ideas? :( I've seen your answer to the question you mentioned above and deffinitely going to try some of the things. My biggest problem for now is that I don't even have the slightest idea what *could* be wrong. Would you also be so kind to "rate" my network structure? It's "conv-ReLU-conv-ReLU-conv-ReLU-pool-linear-linear". The code is in the question. Maybe do you have any suggestions how to improve it? I'm worried that the whole design is not good.